# Crystal Report Viewer is missing in Toolbox Visual studio 2019

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I have installed the latest version of Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2019, with x64 Runtime tool , after restart the VS 2019

The problem is that I can't see the Crystal Report Viewer in the Toolbox.
How can I fix that?

PS: I have already test many solution but any of them seems to be working ( changing Net framework Client Profil to .Net framework ).

[image]

[image]

I have this two packages
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by refreshing the toolbox ( Add new items to the toolbox automatically ) in Visual Studio 2019.